# apache2 not starting

Tags: 12.04, apache2

`sudo service apache2 start` is not working, I am getting

```
* Starting web server apache2                                                  
apache2: Syntax error on line 234 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 51 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/eventum-2.2/CONTRIB: Include takes one argument, Name of the config file to be included
Action 'start' failed.
```

If anybody knows then please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You extracted the eventum application into the apache2 configuration directory, which is definitely the wrong place.

```
sudo mv /etc/apache2/conf.d/eventum-2.2 /var/www
service apache2 restart
```